# Format Excel cells to display as '##:##:##'

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, cell-format

I'm trying to format cells in Excel so that they display the total duration of phone calls as `hh:mm:ss`, but Excel is giving me errors.

Sometimes durations are only `mm:ss` (49:10), or even just `ss` (35), and I need them by default to change to `00:49:10` and `00:00:35` respectivly. However, when I select 'Custom' on the 'Number' tab when formatting the cells and enter either `00:00:00` or `##:##:##`, Excel tells me -

> Microsoft Office Excel cannot use the number format you typed.

Also, `hh:mm:ss` will not work for me, as I'm dealing in durations, not times. Is anyone able to tell me how do format this? Thanks.

Comment: to clear it up - please show your input data and how you get the input - is it typed by hand? an import? calculated from other data? is the raw data a string or a time-value (for instance - NOW() would resolve to a number of 41208,5323841435 - at least for me right now)?

Comment: Just seen your edit, and that has answered it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of these:

```
[h]:mm:ss -> displays something like 27:59:59 or 28:00:00 (28 hours)

[m]:ss -> displays something like 180:59 or 181:00 (181 minutes)

[s] ->  displays something like 180 or 181 (181 seconds)
```

you can even extend those to

```
[h]:mm:ss,000
```

to get the milliseconds ;)

And just so you not wonder- a cell which has a value of 1 formatted with my last example would resolve to 24:00:00,000 - as a numeric 1 equals 24 hours in this format. But this is fine - any time-formulas and durations should work well with this.

*Edit:*

Well, there might be just another way, to be closer to what you stated so far:

```
00":"00":"00
```

But now a time like 24:10:05 would have to be entered as a number 241005.

I don't know if this is what you want.

---

Using the time-formats you would have to enter a complete time statement every time - otherwise excel does not know what you mean, when you type in `10` -> are these 10 seconds, minutes or hours? The same goes for 10:15 - is this 10 hours 15 minutes or 10 minutes 15 seconds?

It's just like that, when you can't answer it as a human, don't expect excel to do it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not working. With a cell formatted as `[h]:mm:ss`, 35 minutes and 10 seconds (entered as 35:10) formats as `35:10:00`, rather than `00:35:10`. Also, 10 seconds (entered as 10) formats as `240:00:00` rather than `00:00:10`.

Comment: yes - because you would need to enter them as 00:35:10 or 00:00:10 - would you mind showing how this data is put into your cell? or you would need to use a number like `0,00011574` to get to 10secs

Comment: Your edit did the trick - 00":"00":"00. Enterint `10` shows `00:00:10`, and `1434434` shows `143:44:34`. This is how a report outputs the data (don't ask me why, the software we use is very unique, but not in a good way!), so that is fine for my purposes - they are total durations already, they do not need to be added by Excel.